# Is there a standard file size recommendation to optimize web images?

Tags: website-design, images, image-quality, file-size, optimization

I remember, during college (2008), my web design professor made a point to keep all images' file size **at/below 40K** (didn't matter what the dimensions). I have made an effort to do so ever since, especially with mobile optimization being so important.

But now, with broadband and LTE/4G speed internet, larger data plans... and I being out of college for a while... are there any file size (not dimensions) standards out there?

*Side note:
My project is dealing with product photography. I'm looking at Amazon.com as a benchmark and note that their product images are under 40K (usually) with a zoom image under 100K (usually).*

Comment: One thing to consider: Content Management Systems, such as Wordpress, have become much more important and prominent since 2008. Many of them automatically reduce the dimensions of and compress images for you - especially depending on the context (thumbnail versus full image). Using your example, I'd assume Amazon has automated the process quite a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the risk of being frowned upon for not answering your question, I would say this: don't worry about file size. Instead, worry about load time. They're certainly directly correlated, but the difference is that load time is universally applicable. A 2MB file might load instantly on a powerful hosting site such as imgur but not on an inexpensive shared hosting service.

To determine your answer, you can run load time benchmarks before you begin designing. Upload a simple page with a few images of varying file sizes to the future site host and record the network performance. You can do this yourself using [browser developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network), or you could use an [external service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8529407/1832306).

Try pushing the limit to see what you can get away with. Keep in mind that downloading a 5MB file is not the same as downloading 10 512KB files because of the overhead involved. If the load time for the entire page is taking a few seconds, it's probably a good idea to reconsider an image-heavy site design.

Your question focuses on images, but there is so much more to optimize beyond that. Google has a great resource available for this kind of thing: [Web Performance Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro). Not all of the advice there will necessarily apply to your situation. Depending on your expected traffic some of the optimizations might be lead to insignificant performance improvements, but it's a great guide to know what to look out for.

Comment: **Thanks for the great resources!** Certainly, Amazon.com has some great CMS and scripts for image compression (I'm not so lucky), and their design leads to great mobile device optimization. With my company working on a new website and design that should cut down load time and improve performance, I'd like to help my team define a standard for images (obviously our own decision)... However, I was first curious if there is such a standard already out there?